# How to check serial number of NVMe disk?

Tags: server, ssd, nvme

How to check serial number of NVMe disk?

To check serial number for sda and sdb I used:

```
sudo lsblk --raw -o name,type,serial
```

However it does not work for NVMe disks (nvme0n0, nvme0n1 etc). No information about serial number is provided.

Comment: Note that newer versions of lsblk (e.g. mine is from util-linux 2.33.1) do return the serial number for NVMe disks too.

Answer (score 34):

The nvme tool provides options to obtain NVME device information, for example, to install the tool, list the NVME devices and look at the id control fields on /dev/nvme0n1, one would use:

```
sudo apt-get install nvme-cli
sudo nvme list
sudo nvme id-ctrl /dev/nvme0n1
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use good old sysfs and `cat` for that:

```
$ cat /sys/block/nvme0n1/device/serial
PHNH912345441P0B
```

Also as @VZ pointed out modern versions of `lsblk` will output serial numbers for NVMe drives correctly.
Example:

```
$ lsblk -d -o TRAN,NAME,TYPE,MODEL,SERIAL,SIZE
TRAN   NAME         TYPE MODEL               SERIAL             SIZE
       mmcblk0      disk                     0xda61bcdf        14.6G
       mmcblk0boot0 disk                     0xda61bcdf           4M
       mmcblk0boot1 disk                     0xda61bcdf           4M
nvme   nvme0n1      disk INTEL SSDPEKNW010T8 PHNH912345441P0B 953.9G
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that there are two kinds of M.2 drives - the NVMe and the SATA - and they present completely different interfaces.

This is as evidenced by the completely different `dev` device name: `/dev/sd?` for SATA, and `/dev/nvme0n1` for NVMe.

If you download `smartmontools` 6.6, it has experimental NVMe support built in and can show serial number as I remember. (`smartctl -a`, again IIRC).

Otherwise, for NVMe drives you indeed need the nvme-cli tools to be able to do anything more than smartctl can do.

Answer (score -3):

another way to get drive information is to run hdparm

```
sudo hdparm -i /dev/sda /dev/sdb
```

That will give you info on both your disks

FWIW , my laptop has a built in LITEONIT LMT-512L9M-11 MSATA 512GB which does report its serial number via your command and mine. It maybe that your disk doesn't actually return it or that its newness means not enough linux developers have access to them.

Comment: I am able to check serial for sda and sdb.

I cannot check for nvme disks (nvme0n1 , nvme1n1 etc)

Comment: is there an error message ?

Comment: No, there is only information about name and type, serial number is not provided.

Comment: ok it looks like they don't support this mechanism , it could be because they are they own controllers.  maybe lspci might help , the more -v's you give it the more info it gives you.

Comment: /dev/nvme0n1:
 HDIO_DRIVE_CMD(identify) failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
 HDIO_GET_IDENTITY failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device

Comment: edlib: nvme is a bit different from MSATA , it doesn't pretend to be hard disk so its likely doesn't support SMART , maybe lspci